How do Jews who believe in evolution explain kosher species and kilayim?
B"H
In addition to the general discussion of evolution in the Torah, which is discussed elsewhere here, I was just wondering a specific detail:
How do those who propose that the Torah allows for the possibility that all organic life is descended from the same ancestor explain how the Torah prohibits two "kinds" of animals to be worked together, or how the Torah law can have anything to say about any species of animal, such as kosher laws?
Maybe a pig will evolve at a future time to resemble a cow. Is it kosher then? Seemingly not.
The fact that the Torah assigns unique roles to animals based on their "type" (same word used in Genesis when referring to how He created all "types" separate) implies that it's not possible for one "type" to evolve into another.
When one would think that the species change on their own, they can keep changing, which means the Torah's laws wouldn't be eternal.
A pig could easily continue evolving to grow more stomachs or any non kosher species could continue evolving to gain kosher signs.
But the mitzvos and commandments are eternal.
When He creates all species fully formed and individually, then those species will exist forever.
If they just happened to exist the way they do for a limited time, then the commandments of the Torah wouldn't be eternal. But we know they are (Rambam, Mishneh Torah).
On the flip side, certain animal species are required for Mitzvos, like the Paschal lamb, and need to have specific signs in order to be kosher.
What if a lamb later evolved to not have split hooves? Then not only would we not be able to eat what the Torah tells us to eat, but we wouldn't be able to ever offer the Paschal sacrifice again.
All of the daily sacrifices have to be a specific type of kosher animal. If any of those species evolved to a new one, with different features that render it not kosher, then we wouldn't be able to offer those sacrifices.
But we know that we will always be able to offer sacrifices, after moshiach comes, because the laws of the Torah are eternal.
Has there ever been any discussion of this specific point?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Even without this you can ask about species going extinct. How can we be obligated to bring a sheep korban if sheep could all be killed by hunters. (Perhaps a less fanciful sounding example: how could we be obligated to wear tekhelet if murex snails can go extinct?)

I think the idea that humans would allow any edible kosher animal to evolve to become non-kosher is inane. If a Jew owns a cow that gives birth to a calf with a mutation that eliminates the split in its hooves, that calf won’t be allowed to grow up and breed. It’ll be used for milk or sold to a gentile or something. This is also the case for other kosher animals, like chickens, farmed deer, sheep, and more. It can also be applied to farmed fish, like salmon, tuna, and cod. It’s just not gonna happen.

And non-kosher animals, like kosher ones, are the way they are for a reason. Obviously, something about their normal environment makes it necessary for them to lack the characteristics of kosher animals, and to have other characteristics instead. Things don’t randomly just “evolve”. There has to be incentive, or the mutation cannot spread via natural selection, and either becomes extinct or remains confined to a small population. And very large changes, like evolving extra stomachs, take consistent incentive for millions of years. That  can’t happen to our food. It just can’t.


Has there ever been any discussion of this specific point?

Rabbi Dovid Brown asserts the same point as you in his work "Mysteries of the Creation". In it, he points out that all of the minim were created at ma'aseh bereshit, and it is not possible for any new minim to come into being, even though it is possible for new species within a min to diversify. Chullin 70b is proof the offspring can never be a new min from its parents.
He gives the example of the zunin, which the midrash (Bereshit Rabbah 28:8) claims diversified from wheat before the mabul, and therefore is no kilayim with wheat.
I am not saying this argument is water-tight, but it certainly seems to be the same argument you are making.

How would he explain the fact that mules diversified after the flood (Genesis 36:24), but they're considered a different species (Kilayim 1:6)? (In fact this seems to disprove the question's premise that evolution of one species to another is impossible)

@ba mules are cross breeds, not diversifications

The issue under discussion is not the definition of a cross breed or of a diversification, but of a species. If you say mules are a separate species, then it's not true what he says that no new species can come into being. If you say mules aren't a separate species then you are making the definition of a species even farther from the halachic definition, which makes the question even stronger (unless you have a different understanding of what defines a halachic species other than כלאים זה בזה?).

@ba mules aren’t a “new species” that “arose” from a parent species. They’re a crossbreed, as old as the two species it comes from, with the Halachic status of a “type” of animal. Your argument is based on an arbitrary interpretation of a technicality in the translation.

@ba In my answer I defined different minim as subject to kilayim, and species that diversified from a min to not be subjected to kilayim with the original min. Mules seem to be not a new species within a min, nor a new min, but rather a cross breed that retains a combined status of 2 minim, and this seems to be confirmed by Kilayim 8:4. Therefore it is likely that the reason a mule cannot be kilayim with a horse is because of the donkey component (but an interesting sheyla might be why is it kilayim in the case that its mother was a horse? 8:4 implies forbidden, but why?)

@QwertyCTRL. The original question is asking about the correspondence of "kind" and "type" in Torah law to "species" according to science/evolution. Either the halachic type corresponds to the species, or it doesn't. The assumption of the question is that they should correspond, and according to this answer Rabbi Dovid Brown says they do correspond.  But if a mule is a halachic type, but it's not a species according to science (I take it that you're using "crossbreed" as a scientific term, not a halachic term), then species and type don't correspond, and the question stands.

@RabbiKaii Kilayim 1:6 is talking about בהמתך לא תרביע כלאים. Kilayim 8:4 is talking about לא תחרוש בשור ובחמור יחדיו. When we say of two species כלאים זה בזה we're talking about the former.


Maybe a pig will evolve at a future time to resemble a cow. Is it kosher then? Seemingly not.

It may be kosher then, Bekhorot 24a states

If one saw a young animal resembling a pig that was trailing after a ewe, the ewe is exempt from having its future offspring counted a firstborn. And the pig-like animal is forbidden for consumption “until he comes and instructs righteousness to you” (Hosea 10:12), i.e., until Elijah the prophet arrives and determines the halakha.

Rabbenu Bahye (Vayikra 11:4) writes that some interpret a Midrash (Tanhuma Buber Sh'mini, Kohelet Rabbah 1:9) that a pig will be kosher in the future. See also Recanati (Shmini), Shlah (Haye Sarah), and plenty of other Aharonim.
Obviously many (like Radvaz 2:828 and R' Bahye himself) interpret that Midrash differently.

Yes it will be kosher in the future because Hashem will cause it's body to change. But this is not a question of evolution, that's talking about divine intervention.

why cant there be hashgacha pratit in evolution?

Hashga ha pratis means Hashem directs all of the laws of nature. The incident you are describing where Hashem will change the body of the pig is a totally miraculous event. It has no place according to the current laws of nature

ומן הנסים הגדולים המפורסמים אדם מודה בנסים הנסתרים שהם יסוד התורה כלה, שאין לאדם חלק בתורת משה רבינו עד שנאמין בכל דברינו ומקרינו שכלם נסים אין בהם טבע ומנהגו של עולם
https://www.sefaria.org/Ramban_on_Exodus.13.16.1

According to Malbim, sefer haCarmel, the pig is called חזיר not for reasons of future kashrut, which is a late kabbalistic chidush. Pigs have a very short neck, and in order to see what happens in the back they need to turn back, as if returning, in Hebrew חזר.

@Coreofreality I don't understand, if this question based on the premise that there exists a natural process of evolution of species, how is it that a change in the body of a pig is impossible "according to the current laws of nature"
